# Grammar generating odd number of 1s

Tags: formal-grammars

I have the language $L = \{w ∈ \{0, 1, 2\}^∗ \mid \text{the number of 1s in $w$ is odd}\}$.

I am stuck halfway through this process.

I have

$$
\begin{align*}
    &A \to 0A \mid \epsilon \\
    &B \to 2B \mid \epsilon \\
    &C \to AB \mid BA
\end{align*}
$$

This should take care of 0s and 2s.

Now I have this, but I'm not sure if this is right

$$
\begin{align*}
    &X \to 1Y \mid Y1 \\
    &Y \to YC1C1 \mid C \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Construct a DFA for your language, and convert it to a regular grammar.

Comment: When we are not sure about something in mathematics, we try to prove it.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Imagine yourself trying to check if a string has an odd number of ones. Now build a DFA that works in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the language in a part that assures that the number of 1s is odd (like, one 1), and another part of the language that **maintains** that. Similar to induction. So the first step is to write

$$S \rightarrow A1A$$

This makes sure there is at least one $1$ in our grammar, and $A$ is must maintain that. Any number of $0$s or $2$s have no effect, as well as the empty string:

$$A \rightarrow 0A \mid A0$$
$$A \rightarrow 2A \mid A2$$
$$A \rightarrow \lambda$$

However, if $A$ contains a $1$, it must contain at least another one. How can we enforce this? Simple! We re-use $S$, which already enforces this:

$$A \rightarrow 1S\mid S1$$

Note that I made every rule symmetrical regarding order. This is not a good practice in general when writing grammars for actual parsing, as it leads to highly ambiguous grammars. However here the focus is on getting the requirements right, so having not to worry about order at all makes it a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler approach, which converts a DFA to a grammar:

$$
\begin{align*}
&S\to 0S \mid 2S \mid 1A \\
&A\to 0A \mid 2A \mid 1S \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Here $S$ generates all strings with an odd number of 1s, and $A$ generates all strings with an even number of 1s. You can check that the grammar is unambiguous.